# Rails 3 mailer for a model without an email attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to create a PageMailer which emails users when someone interacts with one of their pages.

The User has_many pages, and so the page email is defined as `user.email`

I have tried attr_reader in the Page model, and also I've declared an email method, neither are currently working

I'm getting an error message which states:  `undefined method 'email' for <Page:0x512000d4>`

Can anyone suggest a simple workaround?

thanks

Paul

Comment: sorry,  that error message is: undefined method 'email' for <Page#0x...>

Comment: Hard to say without any code! Personally I would be passing both the user and the page objects to the mailer.

Comment: Hi Frederick,  I tried that and it complains that I'm passing the wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: obviously you'd need to setup the mailer to accept 2 arguments, but without seeing what you're doing I'm just guessing

Comment: that's what I've done ... please ref. http://pastebin.com/XFiaJT4q

Comment: That looks like it should work. What errors are you getting (note that you need to restart delayed_job for it to pick up changes - it might be simpler to not use delayed job until you've got things working)

Answer (score 0):

```
send_fb_like_email(user, page)
undefined method 'email' for <Page:0x512000d4>
```

The error says it's trying to find the "email" of a "page".
Looks like you've accidentally switched the user and page params in one of the calls to the method. Go check all the places where you *call* this email method and see if you've done that.

Comment: Hi Taryn,  that's not actually the case ... I had previously tried a 'page_mailer' with just one param - a page object ... It was telling me that email was not a method of Page,  when it clearly was!

Comment: is it a method of Page (the class) or of *a* page (ie an instance of Page) ?

Comment: Also - please note, I can only comment based on the code that you actually show us... and the code that you have actually showed us show that it's trying to access email from a user object, not a page object, and that the error is that it's trying to access email form a page object.